# となし in 「往{ゆ}け八紘を宇{いえ}となし」

Tags: grammar, words, song-lyrics

I'm currently listening to 「愛国行進曲」, which is apparently a Shōwa-era patriotic song. It is written in a rather confusing mix of modern and Classical Japanese, but I think I can understand most of it except for 「往{ゆ}け八紘を宇{いえ}となし」. What is となし? Is it と無し? That doesn't seem to make any sense...

Comment: Also, another weird part is 「正しき平和　打ちたてん」. Where does 打ちたてん come from? Is it 打ち立てぬ (= 打ち立てない)? That seems weird, as this seems to be meant as a command, not a negative!

Comment: Perhaps that ん is [助動詞「む」](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%80), the ancestor of modern 助動詞「う」？

Comment: Wikipedia actually lists the lyrics as "打ち立てむ" http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%84%9B%E5%9B%BD%E8%A1%8C%E9%80%B2%E6%9B%B2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be the 連用形 of 為す, so that the meaning is roughly

> 八紘を宇となし
>   make the whole world our home

Also, ん is most likely む, which carries the meaning of ～う・～よう, giving

> 正しき平和打ちたてん
>   let us establish true peace

Comment: So it means roughly 正しい平和を打ち立てよう?

Comment: Yes, I would think so.

Comment: Ohh. Maybe I had misunderstood a lot of ~ん in lyrics and whatnot? How about the case of the last line of さくらさくら? 見にゆかん = 見るために、行かない or 行こう? Both seem to make sense, as to see something you need to stop ゆくing, but if it is far away, you need to ゆく there first...

Comment: It is most definitely 行こう.

Comment: @user54609 Why 見る *ため* に? ます-stem + に is such a common construction... I would say that 見に行こう should be the contemporary translation.

Comment: Sorry, my Japanese is mostly learning under a rock with Wikipedia and textbooks; the only Japanese text I read frequently is Japanese Wikipedia articles about Japanese :P